# How to call the external controller from angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am creating a project using `angularJS`. Here I have many controllers in different HTML files script section. In my home page file, I have to call these controllers and scope values without referring the `scripts` in the head section of the HTML page. Is there any possible way to call the external controller from script section without using any third party plugin. Also while analyzing about that I got some suggestion to use resolve option in config. Can you please anyone suggest me to use resolve option to achieve my goal.

Please refer my below code

In my html page,

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
mainApp .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    // home page
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'Samples/accordion.html',
          controller: "AddStudentController",
      })
 });

my html section: 
<h1> I am controller 1</h1>
<script>
 <h1>AddStudent</h1>
 mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
 $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
  });
</script>
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: For the controller to be available you need to include the controller file in the script tag, the other way is to use RequireJS, with RequireJS you can dynamically load controller and its dependencies.

Comment: I have tried with require js but cannot achive my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got idea to complete these by referring below

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Answer (score 1):

If your app loads before the script tags then your angular mainApp will not be recognized and you will get error.

```
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
    mainApp .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // home page
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'Samples/accordion.html',
              controller: "AddStudentController",
          })
     }).controller('AddStudentController',function($scope){
           //first controller
     }).controller('GeStudentController',function($scope){
           //first controller
     });

    my html section: 
    <div ng-controller="AddStudentController">
    <h1> I am controller 1</h1>

     <h1>AddStudent</h1>
    </div>
 <div ng-controller="GetStudentController">
    <h1> I am controller 1</h1>

     <h1>GetStudent</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi, i have lot no of controllers in different html file. for example accordion.html have one controller called "AddStudent". Like this i have more no of the html files that contains diffenct controllers with scope values. So i want to load these controllers in my main JS file using config option. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: i would suggest you take a look into [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) it explain what you need :-) good luck